# MySQL query problem with 'like' and confusion

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I need to use a string query to make a DB search for a C# program that interacts with MySQL server. What I want to find is a name that is 'like' one of my other variables (nameVar)

I have the following query in a C# program

```
string q = "SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE 
             WHERE name is like %?nameVar%";
```

As soon as execute the query in my program I get a syntax error telling me that syntax near 
'like' is incorrect. As soon as I remove the "%" sign, it works fine.

I am confused, is mandatory to remove the % sign while building a query string?

Comment: I would recommmend to use a parameterized query to prevent SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Above is a parameterized query or isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameter is replacing the `?nameVar` part, including quotes. If the param is "TEST", your query gets presented as

```
string q = "SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE 
             WHERE name is like %'TEST'%";
```

As you can see, the % signs are out of place.  either include them from the C# program into `namevar`, or change the query to

```
string q = "SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE 
             WHERE name is like '%' + ?nameVar + '%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to quote the query:

```
string q = "SELECT * from table where name is like '%?nameVar%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings in SQL need to be enclosed in single quotes:

```
string q = "SELECT * 
              FROM TABLE 
             WHERE name LIKE '%?nameVar%' ";
```

Also, there's no `IS` operator when using `LIKE`.

Comment: Yup, I guess I leave that "IS" out. That was by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to leave out 'is'.

[MySQL Pattern Matching](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: Yeah, i will leave that IS outside!

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fields LIKE '%phrase%'
```

Comment: It is a parameterized query so I have to use ? aswell

Comment: Hmmm, I guess then "SELECT * FROM WHERE fields LIKE ?", and the parameters should be "%" & var & "%"